In the open-source library Filament, how do you set a pure white background for a Skybox?
I am currently using the iOS demo code hello-gltf. I have modified the setupIbl function in App.cpp. Here is the modified code:
void App::setupIbl() {
    
    const uint32_t textureSize = 1;
    const uint8_t whitePixel[] = { 255, 255, 255, 255 };

    filament::Texture::PixelBufferDescriptor buffer(whitePixel, sizeof(whitePixel),
        filament::Texture::Format::RGBA, filament::Texture::Type::UBYTE);

    filament::Texture *whiteCubeTexture = filament::Texture::Builder()
        .width(textureSize)
        .height(textureSize)
        .levels(1)
        .sampler(filament::Texture::Sampler::SAMPLER_CUBEMAP)
        .format(filament::Texture::InternalFormat::RGBA8)
        .build(*engine);

    for (int face = 0; face < 6; face++) {
        filament::Texture::PixelBufferDescriptor faceBuffer(whitePixel, sizeof(whitePixel),
            filament::Texture::Format::RGBA, filament::Texture::Type::UBYTE);
        whiteCubeTexture->setImage(*engine, 0, 0, 0, face, textureSize, textureSize, 1, std::move(faceBuffer));
    }

    // white cube texture
    app.skyboxTexture = whiteCubeTexture;
    app.skybox = filament::Skybox::Builder()
        .environment(app.skyboxTexture)
        .build(*engine);

    scene->setSkybox(app.skybox);

    // sun light
    app.sun = EntityManager::get().create();
    LightManager::Builder(LightManager::Type::SUN)
        .castShadows(true)
        .direction({0.0, -1.0, 0.0})
        .build(*engine, app.sun);
    scene->addEntity(app.sun);
}

Question 1:
I just want to a pure white Skybox, but it currently appears black. Why is this happening?
Question 2:
In the Android demo code, I see a class like HDRLoader that can load HDR files directly without the need for pre-compilation. However, on iOS, it seems that HDR resources must be pre-compiled using Xcode, which is very unfriendly. How can I directly load and use HDR files in iOS like in the Android code?
Because on the design resources side, HDR files can only be delivered via RESTful API access.
